# Sql Logical operators.. AND & OR combination

Tags: sql

I have a sql code with filter conditions as below

```
Select * from TABLE A
Where Col1<>0
and(col2 is not null or col3 is not null)
```

Please explain why i do not see any records in the output when a record has NULL on both col2 and col3.

How is this is evaluated??

Comment: That is the logic you have implemented.  Are you asking why it works?

Comment: *"when a record has NULL on both col2 and col3."* because, if you translate it in syntax, this provide : `NULL is not null or NULL is not null` which is false.

Comment: Thanks cid.. my mistake.. I implemented it correctly but then while doing Root cause analysis, somhow got confused.. work pressure:).. Missed simple thing..

Answer (score 0):

Null check for Col1 should be the first in condition. if Col1 is null then checking null with a value e.g. Col1 = 0 or Col1 <> 0 will always return false. Below an alternate way to deal with nulls in Col1.

```
Select * from TABLE A
Where isnull(Col1, 0) <> 0
and col2 is not null
```